# window.history.pushState the pages do not update

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using window.history.pushState() to change the url of the page and put it in the history list, everything works but I have a problem, if for example in a page I execute an operation (ajax), which changes the values ​​in the db and textually update a part of the page, if I browse elsewhere and return to this page, I find what was originally there and not the changes made, to see them correctly I have to refresh the page.

I don't currently use any caching systems
Some contents are loaded with ajax others are directly on the page

window.history.pushState() is used only in the home page in the others I don't need it even if it happens on all

in the example page I have this code

```
function init() {

  $('#weekDays').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {

      var modal = $(this);

      $.ajax({
          type: 'post',
          cache: false,
          url: '/my_account/get_giorni_chiusura_sett',
          dataType: 'html'
      }).done(function(data) {
          modal.find('.modal-content').html(data);
      });

  });

  $('body').on('click', '#save-closing-days', function() {
      var dataString = $('#form-weekdays-close').serialize();

      $.ajax({
          type: 'post',
          cache: false,
          url: '/my_account/set_giorni_chiusura_sett',
          data: dataString,
          dataType: 'json'
      }).done(function(data) {
          if (data.update === 'ok') {
              var daysClose = $.map(data.giorni, function(v) {
                  return '<strong>' + v + '</strong>';
              }).join(' - ');

              $('#list-days-close').html(daysClose);

              $('#weekDays').modal('hide');
          }
      });
  });
}
```

when I arrive in the page the content is loaded without ajax and generated by php, the first function loads the content in the modal upon opening, the second one saves / updates the data on the database and updates the text on the DOM

Closing days: ***Saturday*** - ***Sunday***

Update and become

Closing days: ***Sunday***

Now I move to other pages from the menu and back, but I find it again:
***Saturday*** - ***Sunday***

If I reload the page, the data is updated

Comment: How are you managing cache? How are you loading the data to be displayed?

Comment: Add some code please.

Answer (score 0):

The History API doesn't maintain the state of the DOM for you. You need to do that yourself. [MDN has a good guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API/Working_with_the_History_API) but the short version is:

**When** the user clicks a link **then** your JS should prevent the default behaviour **and** call `pushState` to change the URL **and** use DOM methods to update the page to match what the server would send for that URL.

**When** the user presses the *back* button in their browser **and** [a `popstate` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate) fires **then** your JS should read the URL (and state data if applicable) from the event **and** using DOM methods to update the page to match what the server would send for that URL (i.e. undoing the changes from the previous paragraph).

Comment: This is ok, but specifically, as I said, here I don't use the History API, I only use it in the home where I have a google map and here I retrieve the parameters from the url and update the page with ajax so that it shows the correct data for example www.mysite.com/value1/value2/value3 if I go back and retrieve the parameters from the url I show the map and the correct markers, in the example page I don't use the History API, but this problem affects everywhere I don't know if somehow it is reflected here too, even if I don't know how.

Comment: Also in the home for example, if I am not logged in the login button appears in the menu, if I log in there should be the logout button, but instead it remains login until I refresh the page

Comment: I don't understand, I removed all the window.history.pushState related part, so now everything should be normal, but it still has the same behavior

Comment: OK, I found the problem, I am using a new version of MAMP PRO and the problem is due to OPchache, so it is not a history related problem